# CAS server asking authentication after refreshing login page

Tags: cas, jasig

I am using CAS server.at starting i am giving username and password then i am redirection to my required page.but when i refreshed my page then again it is redirecting to previous page and asking username and password.

can any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not really authenticated on application client side : what CAS client do you use ? Is there a `ticket` parameter when you come back on your application ? Is this ticket validated by your CAS server ?